# AngularJs Directive not getting invoked only for one of its occurence as a HTML tag

Tags: html, angularjs, directive

I am working at a support AngularJS project and am stuck at a defect.
There is a directive `fsm-sticky-header` :

```
<thead fsm-sticky-header scroll-body="#orderDiv" test-view= "'#test3'" scroll-stop="0" scrollable-container="'#leftList'">
```

This directive is used at 3 places  with different attribute's values.
Initially directives for its 3 occurrences is getting invoked 3 times .

But after I click something on the page the whole page reloads again and now the directive is getting called for only 2 of its occurrence not 3. 
The HTML above and below the 3rd directive's HTML tag (the one for which directive is not invoked )  is working fine .

Having limited AngularJS knowledge I am unable to even imagine of a single reason because of which this is happening .
How can a particular occurrence of directive not get invoked if others are getting invoked?

HTML Code for the directives :

```
 <table id="priceCheckTab">
                <thead ng-show="($root.hideDetailFull && $root.hideList && !$root.hideListFull) ||($root.hideDetailFull && !$root.hideList && $root.hideListFull)"
                       fsm-sticky-header scroll-body="#priceCheckTab" test-view= "'#test3'" scroll-stop="0" scrollable-container="'#leftList'">
                <tr ng-show="$root.customPriceCheck" style="background-color: white">
                    <th colspan="10" style="text-align: left">
                        <h2 class="l-section-heading">Price Check <span
                                ng-if="!$root.customPriceCheck" class="item-list__price-check_maximize"
                                ng-click="togglePriceCheckList()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                       <span ng-if="$root.customPriceCheck" class="item-list__price-check_minimize"
                             ng-click="togglePriceCheckList()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                        </h2>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="2">Product</th>
                    <th>Date created</th>
                    <th style="word-break:normal" >Created by</th>
                    <th class="fullViewList" style="display:none">Q2A Ref No.</th>
                    <th class="fullViewList" style="display:none">Term</th>
                    <th class="fullViewList" style="display:none">&nbsp;NRC</th>
                    <th class="fullViewList" style="display:none">&nbsp;MRC</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
```

2nd Occurrence is similar .
3rd occurence of directive in HTML :

```
 <table id="orderDiv">
        <thead fsm-sticky-header scroll-body="#orderDiv" test-view= "'#test3'" scroll-stop="0" scrollable-container="'#leftList'">

        <tr>
            <th style="width: 1.4%"></th>
            <th style="width: 2%" ng-if="!$root.hideListFull"></th>
            <th style="width: 3%" ng-if="$root.hideListFull"></th>
            <th style="width: 2.0%" colspan="2"ng-if="!$root.hideListFull">Product</th>
            <th style="width: 1.0%" colspan="2"ng-if="$root.hideListFull">Product</th>
            <th style="width: 18.6%">Date of Application</th>
            <th style="width: 16.7%;word-break: break-word">Submitted by</th>
            <th style="width: 26.6%;word-break:normal">Work Required</th>
            <th style="width: 15.3%" ng-if="!$root.hideListFull">Q2A Ref No.</th>
            <th style="padding-left:1%;width: 18%" ng-if="!$root.hideListFull">Customer Reference</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
```

The HTML above is working fine except that the directive doesn't get invoked.

Directives JS file  :

```
'use strict';

(function(angular){
var fsm = angular.module('fsm', []);

fsm.directive('fsmStickyHeader', ['$rootScope','$timeout', function($rootScope, $timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            scrollBody: '@',
            scrollStop: '=',
            scrollableContainer: '=',
            contentOffset: '=',
            testView: "=",
            fullView : '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, control){
            console.log(scope.scrollBody);
            var test=$(scope.testView);
            var fullView = $(scope.fullView);

            var content,
                header = $(element, this),
                clonedHeader = null,
                scrollableContainer = $(scope.scrollableContainer),
                contentOffset = scope.contentOffset || 0;

            var unbindScrollBodyWatcher = scope.$watch('scrollBody', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                content = $(scope.scrollBody);
                init();
                unbindScrollBodyWatcher();
            });

            if (scrollableContainer.length === 0){
                scrollableContainer = $(window);
            }


            function setColumnHeaderSizes() {
                if (clonedHeader.is('tr') || clonedHeader.is('thead')) {
                    var clonedColumns = clonedHeader.find('th');
                    header.find('th').each(function (index, column) {
                        var clonedColumn = $(clonedColumns[index]);
                        clonedColumn.css( 'width', column.offsetWidth-16 + 'px');
                    });
                }
            };

            function determineVisibility(){

                var scrollTop = scrollableContainer.scrollTop() + test.offset().top;
                var contentTop = content.offset().top+scrollableContainer.scrollTop()+contentOffset;
                var contentBottom =contentTop+content.outerHeight(false)-100;

                if ( (scrollTop > contentTop) && (scrollTop < contentBottom) ) {

                    if (!clonedHeader){
                        createClone();
                        clonedHeader.css({ "visibility": "visible"});
                    }

                    if ( scrollTop < contentBottom && scrollTop > contentBottom - clonedHeader.outerHeight(false) ){
                        //var top = contentBottom - scrollTop + scope.scrollStop - clonedHeader.outerHeight(false);
                        //clonedHeader.css('top', top + 'px');

                        clonedHeader.css({
                            top: test.offset().top-$(window).scrollTop()+test.height()
                        });

                    } else {
                        calculateSize();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (clonedHeader){
                        /*
                         * remove cloned element (switched places with original on creation)
                         */
                        header.remove();
                        header = clonedHeader;
                        clonedHeader = null;

                        header.removeClass('fsm-sticky-header');
                        header.css({
                            position: 'relative',
                            left: 0,
                            top: 0,
                            width: 'auto',
                            'z-index': 0,
                            visibility: 'visible',
                            'background-color' :''
                        });
                    }
                }
            };

            function calculateSize() {
                clonedHeader.css({
                    top: test.offset().top-$(window).scrollTop()+test.height(),
                    width: header.outerWidth(),
                    left: header.offset().left
                });

                if(scope.scrollBody==="#myTable1" || scope.scrollBody==="#myTable" || scope.scrollBody==="#ServiceInventoryTab"
                    || scope.scrollBody==="#ServiceInventoryTab2" || scope.scrollBody==="#ServiceInventoryTab3" || scope.scrollBody==="#ServiceInventoryTab4"  ) {
                    setColumnHeaderSizes();
                }



            };

            function createClone(){
                /*
                 * switch place with cloned element, to keep binding intact
                 */
                clonedHeader = header;
                header = clonedHeader.clone();
                clonedHeader.after(header);
                clonedHeader.addClass('fsm-sticky-header');
                clonedHeader.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    'z-index': 3,
                    visibility: 'hidden',
                    'background-color' :'white'
                });

                calculateSize();
            };


            $(function(){
                $(window).scroll(function(){
                    if(clonedHeader) {
                        clonedHeader.removeClass('fsm-sticky-header');
                        clonedHeader.css({
                            visibility: 'hidden'
                        });
                    }
                });

            });


            //Function to call on various events on Price Check page for adjusting the sticky header
            function updateHeader(){
                /*if(clonedHeader){
                 header.remove();
                 header=clonedHeader.clone();
                 clonedHeader.after(header);
                 header.removeClass('fsm-sticky-header');
                 header.css({
                 position: 'relative',
                 left: 0,
                 top: 0,
                 width: 'auto',
                 'z-index': 0,
                 visibility: 'visible'
                 });
                 }*/
                determineVisibility();

            }


            function init() {
                scrollableContainer.on('scroll.fsmStickyHeader', determineVisibility).trigger("scroll");
                fullView.on("click.fsmStickyHeader", determineVisibility);
                $("#roleCreate").on("click.fsmStickyHeader", determineVisibility);
                scrollableContainer.on('resize.fsmStickyHeader', determineVisibility);

                //For Service Inventory
                $("#innerEB").on("click.fsmStickyHeader", function () {
                    determineVisibility();
                });

                //For Service Inventory
                $("#innerEA").on("click.fsmStickyHeader", function () {
                    determineVisibility();
                });

                //For Service Inventory
                $("#innerMLLSDH").on("click.fsmStickyHeader", function () {
                    determineVisibility();
                });

                //For Service Inventory
                $("#innerMLLEthernet").on("click.fsmStickyHeader", function () {
                    determineVisibility();
                });

                $("#fullview2").on("click.fsmStickyHeader", function () {
                    updateHeader();
                });

                $("#priceBody").on("click.fsmStickyHeader", function () {
                    updateHeader();
                });

                $("#quoteBody").on("click.fsmStickyHeader", function () {
                    updateHeader();
                });


                scope.$on("roleRow", function (event, args) {
                    determineVisibility();
                });

                $rootScope.$on("cancelEditUser", function () {
                    scrollableContainer.scrollTop(scrollableContainer.scrollTop()+1);
                });

                $rootScope.$on("cancelEditRole", function() {
                    scrollableContainer.scrollTop(scrollableContainer.scrollTop()+1);
                });

                $rootScope.$on("userRow", function () {
                    determineVisibility();
                    scrollableContainer.scrollTop(scrollableContainer.scrollTop()+1);
                });

                scope.$on("inventoryRow", function (event, args) {
                    determineVisibility();
                });

                scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    scrollableContainer.off('.fsmStickyHeader');
                });
            }

            $rootScope.$on('updateStickyHeader', function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scrollableContainer.scrollTop(scrollableContainer.scrollTop()+1);
                }, 0, false);
            });

        }
    };
}]);
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: Why is the whole page reloading ? Aren't you using angular states ?

Comment: check whether those three elements depends on any `ng-if` conditions. please specify more details to get help

Comment: This is impossible to answer. Create a demo at least.

Comment: No ng-if is used , By page reload I meant everything is getting reinitialized . Though i have realized that it is not possible to answer with the available details .I just wanted to know if this is even possible if there are no silly 'ng-if' like mistakes (which is not the case). I will update the question with  more details.